# how can I use jquery variable in mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

At the moment, I am using a $_GET to query mysql and populate a select statement, which works fine. However, I now need to query db using jquery variable and am unable to find a way to use 'depts' instead of '$_GET['dept']'.

I have declared the var global, but realise that you cannot use var in query.

I would be grateful if someone could show me how to amend my code to achieve this. Thanks

php code to populate select

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("sample", $conn);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boxes where department = '{$_GET['dept']}' and status = 1 ORDER BY custref ASC");
?>

    <select name="boxdest[]" id="boxdest" size="7" multiple="multiple">

<?php
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["custref"];?>"><?php echo $row["custref"];?></option>
    <?php
    $i++;
    }
?>

    </select>
```

jQuery change event code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var depts;

    $('#dept').on('change', function() {

    depts = $('#dept option:selected').html();

    if (depts === 'Select a Department') {

       $('#deptResult').html('<p>ERROR: You must Select a department to proceed<p/>').css({'color':'red'});
       $( "#submit" ).prop( "disabled", true );
       return;
    }
      $('#deptResult').html('<p>SUCCESS: You have selected the following dept: ' + depts + '</p>').css({'color':'black'});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is your SQL engine? MySQL?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more and add HTML with `#dept`? If I understand it right, you want to update `select#boxdest` element based on which department is selected, right?

Comment: @Tymek I have added html for #dept. Yes that is correct. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery `ajax()` like:

```
$.ajax({
    url     : 'process.php',
    method  : 'get',
    async   : false,
    data    : {
        variable : value,  
        // you can pass multiple variables like this and this is available in php like $_REQUEST['variable']
    },
    success : function(response){
        // do what ever you want with the server resposne
    }
});
```

process.php:

```
$variable = $_REQUEST['variable'];  // you can use $variable in mysql query
```

Comment: Thanks for that Mayank. Do I code that in the change event? also, how do i use the response value in mysql query.

Comment: **Rudiculusly unsafe!!!** You will allow anybody to delete your database!

Comment: @Tymek How is that so?

Comment: @Tymek bear in mind I have connections script outside of the php page and also include all post injection code. This is only temp measure to test

Comment: @Tymek: Its just an example bro

Answer (score 1):

Can you? **Yes**

You have to use `AJAX`. I can recommend crafting simple API for this task. Example using [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON):

### api.php

```
<?php

function output($arr) {
    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit();
}

if (!isset($_GET['dept'])) {
    output([
        'success' => false,
        "message" => "Department not defined"
    ]);
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    output([
        'success' => false,
        'dept' => $_GET['dept'],
        'message' => "Connect failed: ". $mysqli->connect_error
    ]);
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT(`department`) FROM `boxes`");
if (!$result) {
    output([
        'success' => false,
        'dept' => $_GET['dept'],
        'message' => "Query failed"
    ]);
}

$departments = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $departments[] = $row['department'];
}

if (!in_array($_GET['dept'], $departments)) {
    output([
        'success' => false,
        'dept' => $_GET['dept'],
        'message' => "Department not present in database"
    ]);
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `custref` FROM `boxes` WHERE `department`='". $_GET['dept'] ."' ORDER BY `custref` ASC");
if (!$result) {
    output([
        'success' => false,
        'dept' => $_GET['dept'],
        'message' => "Query failed"
    ]);
}

$custref = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $custref[] = $row['custref'];
}
output([
    'success' => true,
    'dept' => $_GET['dept'],
    'custref' => $custref
]);

$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('select[data-key][data-value]').each(function (i, element) {
        var key = $(element).data("key");
        var value = $(element).data("value");
        var $originSelector = $('[name="'+ key +'"]');

        /**
         * Get options from element by name
         */
        function getOptions () {
            var request = {};
            request[key] = $originSelector.val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "./api.php",
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: request
            }).done(function(data) {
                setOptions(data);
            });
        }
        
        /**
         * Remove old options
         */
        function clearOptions () {
            $(element).find('option').remove();
        }
        
        /**
         * Put new options in input
         */
        function setOptions (data) {
            if (data['success'] && data[value] !== undefined) {
                clearOptions();
                $.each(data[value], function (i, option) {
                    $(element).append('<option value="'+ option +'">'+ option +'</option>');
                });
            }
        }

        getOptions();
        $originSelector.on("change", function () {
            getOptions();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<select name="dept">
    <option value="accounting">Accounting</option>
    <option value="it">Information technology</option>
</select>

<select name="boxdest[]" id="boxdest" size="7" multiple="multiple" data-key="dept" data-value="custref"></select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Tymek. This to me (novice) seems overkill to me. Is all this code necassary just to get single value? very well laid out though and concise.

Comment: PHP is long, because I validated if given `dept` is in the database, but once you wrap your head around it you can extend it's functionality and refactor this code. Let's say you have another pair of inputs where one loads values form database for another: you don't have to change a single line in JS, just add it to API and define different `data-attribute`s in HTML.

Comment: is it possible to code example for the code I posted. Thanks for patience